# Open a folder in mac finder using ProcessBuilder (with accents)

Tags: java, macos

You can use **ProcessBuilder** or **Runtime.getRuntime().exec()** to open a fonder in finder by Java. However I've tried both ways, I just can do it with ProccessBuilder like the code below shows:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("open", path);
Process p = pb.start();

int exitCode = p.waitFor();
```

I can open folder with or without white spaces as well like:

/myFolder/Test Folders/

But I can't open any folder with accents like:

/myFolder/Paulo Casé/

How can I make ProcessBuilder (or something else) to open folders in Java when they are with accents?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is a registered [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7193966). But it has been recently fixed. Update to the latest Java version.

It was happening because Java could not detect File paths containing non-ascii characters.